# Suspend Databinding for a combobox control

Tags: c#, data-binding

I have a ultrawincombobox that is bound to an instance of a class as shown below:

```
DataBindFormObjects()
{
  combobox1.DataBindings.Clear();
  combobox1.DataBindings.Add("Value", objClass, "Status");
}
```

Now I have a specific scenario where I want to change the text or the value of combobox1 when a condition is met and I tried to achieve it using SuspendBinding when the condition is satisfied. The code is shown below:

```
if (combobox2.Text == "Value1" )
{
 BindingManagerBase myBindingManager = BindingContex[objClass, "combobox1"];
 myBindingManager.SuspendBinding();
 combobox1.Text = "ABCD";
}
```

Using the above code I am not able to change the text of combobox1 to ABCD. Can anyone point out where I am going wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you get errors?  Is the ComboBox set to DropDownList?  If so, is "ABCD" in the available list?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I do not get any errors and No it is not set to dropdown list, it just has a single value in it each time it is loaded.

Comment: combobox2 isn't a typo, is it?

Comment: Its not a typo, it is combobox2 and if that condition is met then the combobox1 should display "ABCD"

Comment: Does it work if you comment out the myBindingManager stuff?

Comment: It doesn't, Initially I tried with out suspending and it did not change the text in combobox1, so I tried with suspending it only when this condition is satisfied..but still it doesn't display the expected text...:(

Comment: Clearly it should work without that suspension stuff, so you must have something else going on that prevents the text from changing.  You need to post enough code that duplicates the problem.

Comment: @LarsTech It gave me an error with the below code, it says System.ArgumentException, Child list for field combobox1 cannot be created, any idea where I am going wrong

Comment: if (combobox2.Text == "Value1" )
     {
 BindingManagerBase myBindingManager = BindingContex[objClass, "combobox1"];
 myBindingManager.SuspendBinding();
 combobox1.Text = "ABCD";
}

Comment: I thought we were ignoring that code since you first have to get to a point where you can just simply change the text of the ComboBox.  If you still want to play with the data binding, you can go more direct: `combobox1.DataBindings[0].BindingManagerBase.SuspendBinding();`

Comment: @LarsTech I tried changing it directly with out the databinding stuff, but when I do that the combobox does not display the value that it is supposed to display instead displays the value from the databinding elements...any idea why its doing that?

Comment: Isn't that the entire crux of your post?  It should work, but you haven't posted enough code in your question that duplicates the problem for us.  It changes on my machine.